# Create files in a Github repo from Terraform (based on a local file)

Tags: terraform

I'm having trouble with my terraform setup. I want to add a static file from my local filesystem to a github repository. I use the [Terraform Github Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs) which generally works fine (I do some other stuff that works already).

### Attempt Number 1

This is my code to upload the file:

```
data "local_file" "workflow_assign_issues" {
  filename = "${path.module}/organize-assign-issues.yml"
}
resource "github_repository_file" "workflow_assign_issues" {
  repository          = var.repo_name
  branch              = "main"
  commit_message      = "[Actions Bot] Update Github Actions workflow"
  overwrite_on_create = true
  file                = ".github/workflows/organize-assign-issues.yml"
  content             = data.local_file.workflow_assign_issues.content
}
```

When I run `terraform plan` the contents of the yml file are printed to the console perfectly fine. But when I run `terraform apply` with the plan I saved from the `plan` step I always get this error:

```
Error: PUT https://api.github.com/repos/sebastian-sommerfeld-io/dojo/contents/.github/workflows/organize-assign-issues.yml: 404 Not Found []
   with module.dojo-labels.github_repository_file.workflow_assign_issues,
   on modules/issues/workflows.tf line 5, in resource "github_repository_file" "workflow_assign_issues":
   5: resource "github_repository_file" "workflow_assign_issues" {
```

### Attempt Number 2

Since this results in an error I changed my code. I ditched the `local_file`-data and used the `file`- function directly.

```
resource "github_repository_file" "workflow_assign_issues" {
  repository          = var.repo_name
  branch              = "main"
  commit_message      = "[Actions Bot] Update Github Actions workflow"
  overwrite_on_create = true
  file                = ".github/workflows/organize-assign-issues.yml"
  content             = file("${path.module}/organize-assign-issues.yml")
}
```

But this crashes as well when running `terraform apply`:

```
Error: PUT https://api.github.com/repos/sebastian-sommerfeld-io/website-masterblender-de/contents/.github/workflows/organize-assign-issues.yml: 404 Not Found []
   with module.website-masterblender-de-issues.github_repository_file.workflow_assign_issues,
   on modules/issues/workflows.tf line 1, in resource "github_repository_file" "workflow_assign_issues":
   1: resource "github_repository_file" "workflow_assign_issues" {
```

### Confirming `github_repository_file`-resource works

To confirm the `github_repository_file`-resource works I added a static string as `content` instead of the `file` function. This works and creates the file. But to me this is not really the way to because (1) the yaml file is to large to be an inline file and (2) I could not use yamllint with inline files.

Anyone got an idea? I'm stuck and don't know how to solve this issue.

### UPDATE: New error when I `plan` my config

I added the `workflows` scope to my github token and tried to run this config:

```
data "local_file" "workflow_assign_issues" {
  filename = "${path.module}/assets/workflows/organize-assign-issues.yml"
}

resource "github_repository_file" "workflow_assign_issues" {
  repository          = var.repo_name
  branch              = "main"
  commit_message      = "[Actions Bot] Update Github Actions workflow"
  overwrite_on_create = true
  file                = ".github/workflows/organize-assign-issues.yml"
  content             = data.local_file.workflow_assign_issues.content
}

data "local_file" "workflow_auto_close_issues" {
  filename = file("${path.module}/assets/workflows/organize-auto-close-issues.yml")
}
resource "github_repository_file" "workflow_auto_close_issues" {
  repository          = var.repo_name
  branch              = "main"
  commit_message      = "[Actions Bot] Update Github Actions workflow"
  overwrite_on_create = true
  file                = ".github/workflows/organize-auto-close-issues.yml"
  content             = data.local_file.workflow_auto_close_issues.content
}

data "local_file" "workflow_dependabot" {
  filename = file("${path.module}/assets/workflows/organize-dependabot.yml")
}
resource "github_repository_file" "workflow_dependabot" {
  repository          = var.repo_name
  branch              = "main"
  commit_message      = "[Actions Bot] Update Github Actions workflow"
  overwrite_on_create = true
  file                = ".github/workflows/organize-dependabot.yml"
  content             = data.local_file.workflow_dependabot.content
}
```

Now I get this error (for each file):

```
│ name: "Organize: Dependabot Pull Requests"
│ 
│ # +-------------------------------------------+
│ # |                                           |
│ # |    DO NOT EDIT DIRECTLY !!!!!             |
│ # |                                           |
│ # |    File is managed by terraform.          |
│ # |    Update file in the configs repo so     |
│ # |    you can apply changes to all repos.    |
│ # |                                           |
│ # +-------------------------------------------+
│ 
│ on:
│   push:
│     branches:
│       - main
│     paths:
│       - .github/workflows/organize-dependabot.yml
│   schedule:
│     - cron: '0 12 * * *' # https://crontab.guru
│ 
│ permissions:
│   contents: read
│   issues: write
│   pull-requests: write
│ 
│ jobs:
│   assign-user:
│     name: Assign PRs with label 'dependencies' to user
│     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
│     steps:
│       - name: Get PR and assign user (limited to 'dependencies' by github cli)
│         id: vars
│         env:
│           GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN_REPO_AND_PROJECT }}
│           label: dependencies
│           assignee: ${{ github.actor }}
│         run: |
│           echo "Current Date and Time = $(date +'%Y-%m-%d .. %H:%M:%S')"
│           echo "Current Repo = $GITHUB_REPOSITORY"
│           pr_ids="$(gh pr list --repo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" --search "no:assignee label:$label" --json number --jq '.[].number')"
│           for id in $pr_ids; do
│             echo "Update Pull Request with ID = $id"
│             gh pr edit "$id" --repo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" --add-assignee "$assignee"
│           done
│ 
│   on-failure:
│     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
│     needs: assign-user
│     if: failure()
│     steps:
│       - name: Send Pipeline Status to Google Chat
│         if: always()
│         uses: Co-qn/google-chat-notification@releases/v1
│         with:
│           name: ${{ github.workflow }}
│           url: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CHAT_WEBHOOK }}
│           status: failure
│ : file name too long
│ 
│   with module.website-masterblender-de-issues.data.local_file.workflow_dependabot,
│   on modules/issues/workflows.tf line 37, in data "local_file" "workflow_dependabot":
│   37: data "local_file" "workflow_dependabot" {
```

I'm confused because terraform finds the file and prints the whole file to the console when I run `terraform plan`. So terraform obviously is able to read the file. Why do I get the `file name too long` error message?

Comment: Have you tried actually providing the path to the file instead of using `file` function? In other words, using `content = "${path.module}/organize-assign-issues.yml"`?

Comment: More or less yes. I replaced the `content = file(...)` part with a static string. This was not the path to the file, but the behavior is the same. Using `content = "some-static-string"` results in "some-static-string" being the content of the file. Using your suggestion results in the file path being the content of the newly created file. The file is created at the stated location in the remote repo (`file = ".github/workflows/organize-assign-issues.yml"`). That way I confirmed that the `github_repository_file`-resource itself works.

Comment: Does you token has `workflows` scope?

Comment: I added the `workflows` scope ... but now I get a different error when I `plan` my config ... I updated my question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue in this error message is the part which appears immediately after the contents of the file:

`file name too long`

The data source is trying to use *the contents of the file* as the filename.

It's doing that because you've passed the result of `file` into the `filename` argument:

```
  filename = file("${path.module}/assets/workflows/organize-dependabot.yml")
```

The `file` function reads the contents of the file provided in its argument, and returns the contents. You've then assigned that value -- the contents of the file, not the filename itself -- to the `filename` argument of `local_file`. That's incorrect, because the `filename` argument expects a filename, not the contents of the file.

---

To make this work you'll need to decide whether you want to read the file during configuration evaluation or whether you want to read the file at runtime while Terraform is creating the plan.

If this file will already exist on disk before you run Terraform and will not be modified by applying this configuration then it's safe to refer to treat the file itself as part of your configuration, reading it directly from disk during initial configuration evaluation like this:

```
resource "github_repository_file" "workflow_dependabot" {
  repository          = var.repo_name
  branch              = "main"
  commit_message      = "[Actions Bot] Update Github Actions workflow"
  overwrite_on_create = true
  file                = ".github/workflows/organize-dependabot.yml"
  content             = file("${path.module}/assets/workflows/organize-dependabot.yml")
}
```

In that case you don't need `data "local_file"` at all, because Terraform Core will read the file from disk as part of evaluating the built-in `file` function.

The `local_file` data source from the `hashicorp/local` provider is only needed if you are reading a file that's created dynamically as part of applying the configuration. It being a data resource allows Terraform to treat the file just as any other data source, reading it at the appropriate time while respecting dependencies in your configuration. For example, if you had another part of your configuration that was *creating* the file then you'd need to use the local file data source to read it so that Terraform can see that it mustn't read the file until the file has been created:

```
# This resource is just an example of one way that
# the file might be created dynamically during the
# apply step.
resource "local_file" "example" {
  filename = "${path.module}/assets/workflows/organize-dependabot.yml"
  content  = "(put YAML content in here)"
}

data "local_file" "example" {
  filename = local_file.example.filename
}

resource "github_repository_file" "workflow_dependabot" {
  repository          = var.repo_name
  branch              = "main"
  commit_message      = "[Actions Bot] Update Github Actions workflow"
  overwrite_on_create = true
  file                = ".github/workflows/organize-dependabot.yml"
  content             = data.local_file.example.content
}
```

This is a contrived example because it would be pointless to write a file to disk just to read it back again, but the point here is that the `filename` argument of `data "local_file"` should typically be populated from some other resource that is the one creating the file, and then Terraform can see that reading the file depends on writing the file and so make the steps happen in the correct order.

In your case though it seems like you just have static files on disk as part of your configuration, and so you should use the first example above and not include any `data "local_file"` blocks in your configuration at all.